# Subgroups of finite and infinite groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Would somebody check the correctness of my proofs?

**Theorem.** Let $H$ be a non-empty subset of a finite group $G$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $H$ is closed under the group operation.

Proof. If $H$ is a subgroup then it is closed. Suppsoe $H$ is closed.

1. Associativity follows from $G$
2. Since $H$ is finite, there exist $x,y\in  \mathcal N$ with $x\gt y$ such that $g^x=g^y$ where $g\in H$. So $g^{x-y}=e$ (the identity). $e=g^{x-y}\in H$ because it's closed.
3. $gg^{x-y-1}=e$ so $g^{-1}=g^{x-y-1}\in H$ again because it's closed.

**Therorem.** Let $H$ be a non-empty subset of a group $G$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $gh^{-1}\in H, \forall g,h\in H$

Proof. If $H$ is a sugroup then $gh^{-1}\in H$ by closure and inverses. Suppose that $gh^{-1}\in H$ for all $g,h\in H$.

1. Associativity follows from $G$
2. $gg^{-1}=e\in H$
3. $eg^{-1}=g^{-1}\in H$
4. $h^{-1}\in H$ for all $h\in H$, so $g(h^{-1})^{-1}=gh\in H$

Comment: You are assuming what needs to proven.

Comment: Also need $H$ is non-empty.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I did not get that. I'm proving both directions of the equivalence.

Comment: @Rebecca I fixed that by making $H$ proper.

Comment: Actually, it just made it worse.  Now, according to the theorm: "$G$ is closed" implies "$G$ is a proper subgroup".  It should be "Let $H$ be a non-empty subset of $G$.  Then $H$ is a subgroup if and only if $H$ is closed."

Comment: For first theorem's proof, you are using both the properties that $H$ is closed as well as $H$ is finite while trying to prove it.

Comment: @hjpotter92 $H$ is finite is given because $G$ is finite.

Comment: What does 'closed' mean in this context?  Your second proof looks fine.

Comment: @Rhys: Closed means that $gh\in H$ whenever $g,h\in H$.

Comment: Okay, just checking.  'Closed under the group operation' should be written at least once.

Comment: @Rebecca ${}{}{}{}$ Now?

Comment: @saadtaame: It looks good, now. I would rephrase the statements, though, since at present it suggests that there is such a thing as an "empty (sub)group." For the first one, I would say "Given a non-empty subset $H$ of a finite group $G,$ $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $H$ is closed." For the second, I would say "Given a non-empty subset $H$ of a group $G,$ $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $\forall g,h\in H$, $gh^{-1}\in H$."

Comment: Alternately, for the first one, say: "Given a subset $H$ of a finite group $G,$ $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $H$ is non-empty and closed." For the second one, say: "Given a subset $H$ of a group $G,$ $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $H$ is non-empty and $\forall g,h\in H,$ $gh^{-1}\in H$." Either way, the necessary adjustments to the proofs will be minor.

Comment: Looks even better! The only thing I'd adjust now is to point out (in both proofs) that $g$ is an arbitrary fixed element of $H$--at least one such exists since $H$ is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

- I prefer "Associativity is inherited from G", although this is a personal opinion.
- In both proofs, you haven't used the non-emptiness of $H$.  "Since $H$ is non-empty, there exists $g \in H$."
- I'm uncomfortable with the possibility that $x-y-1=0$ in $gg^{x-y-1}$, without defining what $g^0$ is.
- You also seem to be getting a bit informal in the write-up of the second proof; what is $g$?, what is $h$?, etc.  Why not explain what you've shown at each step? "Thus, the identity element is in $H$." and "Thus, $g \in H$ implies $g^{-1} \in H$."
- I generally think that $\forall$ and $\exists$ should be used only in formal logic, or as a blackboard shortcut.
- Finally, to prove Theorem 2, having proved Theorem 1, you only need closure.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seems good; but the check about associativity is not necessary.

Here's how I like to prove this proposition.

---

What you have to prove is that $1\in H$ and that, for any $x\in H$, then $x^{-1}\in H$, under the hypotheses that $H$ is not empty and closed under the operation in $G$.

Since $H$ is not empty, there is an element $y\in H$. Define the map
$$
f\colon H\to H,\qquad f(x)=xy.
$$
This is well defined, by the closure of $H$ under the operation. Now $f$ is an injective map: indeed, if $x_1,x_2\in H$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $x_1y=x_2y$, whence $x_1yy^{-1}=x_2yy^{-1}$ (this can be done in $G$, which is a group).

Since $H$ is finite, we conclude that $f$ is surjective. In particular there exists $e\in H$ such that $f(e)=y$, that is $ey=y$, which means $e=1$.

We have thus proved that $1\in H$; so there is $z\in H$ with $f(z)=1$, which means $zy=1$, that is, $z=y^{-1}\in H$.

Since $y$ is an arbitrary element of $H$, we are done.

---

Note that we don't need $G$ to be finite.